# ios - finding upcoming birthdays in a week

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to find the upcoming birthdays in a week on iOS. I pulled the birthday data from Facebook and trimmed the year part (since it may not be available for some users depending on user's privacy settings) hence the birthday data is an `NSString` with date format `@"MM/dd"`

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter dateFormatterWithFormat:@"MM/dd"] retain];
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *todayComponents = [dateFormatter.calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit
                                                              fromDate:today];
todayComponents.hour = 13;
todayComponents.minute = 0;
todayComponents.second = 0;
today = [dateFormatter.calendar dateFromComponents:todayComponents];

[facebookFriends enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *friend,
                                              NSUInteger idx,
                                              BOOL *stop) {

    NSDate *birthday = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[friend objectForKey:@"birthday"]];
    NSDateComponents *birthdayComponents = [dateFormatter.calendar components:NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit
                                                                     fromDate:birthday];
    birthdayComponents.year = todayComponents.year;
    birthdayComponents.hour = todayComponents.hour;
    birthdayComponents.minute = todayComponents.minute;
    birthdayComponents.second = todayComponents.second;

    birthday = [dateFormatter.calendar dateFromComponents:birthdayComponents];
    NSDateComponents *difference = [dateFormatter.calendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit
                                                             fromDate:today
                                                               toDate:birthday
                                                              options:0];
    if (difference.day >= 0 &&
        difference.day < 7) { // 7 days in a week
        [birthdaysToShow[difference.day] addObject:friend];
    }
}];
[dateFormatter release];
```

where `dateFormatterWithFormat:` is a category on `NSDateFormatter`:

```
+ (NSDateFormatter *)dateFormatterWithFormat:(NSString *)formatString
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
    dateFormatter.calendar = calendar;
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = formatString;
    dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];

    return [dateFormatter autorelease];
}
```

2 questions here:

1- I have a bug in this code, if there is less than a week to the new year, I won't be able to display birthdays in the new year since I'm setting the year of the birthday to the current year and `difference.day` will be way less than 0 for the birthdays in the new year. How do I go about fixing that?

2- As you can see from the above snippet I'm doing a lot of dancing: first I get today's date and time with `[NSDate date]`, then I rip it to its components and assemble it back to an `NSDate` with a time at noon rather than the current time. The reason I'm doing this is that if `[NSDate date]` returns a date whose time is say 23:00:00, and if the birthday time is 00:00:00 (1 hour later, meaning the birthday is tomorrow), then `difference.day` equals `0` instead of the desired `1`. Is what I did in the above snippet the proper way of doing this? I think I might be doing too much work for something seemingly so simple, how would you fix this arrangement so that I don't have to slice `today` and `birthday` into components and put them back into an `NSDate`?

Comment: Have you seen ["Checking when a date falls"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendricalCalculations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007836-SW9) in the Date and Time Programming Guide? For point 2, you could also get the hours' difference; if the day difference is 0 but the hours are positive, that should mean it's the next day.

Comment: Place the birthdates in an ordered list, starting from 01/01.  Find the current date in the list and scan forward until you encounter the end of the list or a date more than a week out.  If you encounter the end of the list, and the current date is within a week of the end of the year, scan the front of the list to fill out the week.

Comment: You could set birthdayComponents.year to the "correct" year for each result for their "next" birthday. In other words if birthday month < current month then birthday year is current year+1 (but remember to handle correctly if same month but we've already past their birthday).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the right year for each birthdayComponents object:

```
birthdayComponents.year=todayComponents.year; //default

if(birthdayComponents.month< todayComponents.month) birthdayComponents.year=todayComponents.year+1; //their next birthday is next year.

if(birthdayComponents.month==todayComponents.month && birthdayComponents.day<todayComponents.day) birthdayComponents.year=todayComponents.year+1; //their next birthday is next year
```